# how to redirect printf output from application to script executing the application?

Tags: c, shell

When I call a external application program in shell script, how can I

get the output of printf in executable application(a.out) and print them on shell prompt?

script:

```
STATUS_CMD="AGQMI stop $PDH $CID"

`$STATUS_CMD` 

clear_state

echo done
```

AGQMI is my application which have printf for success and failure cases, i need to see them in shell output but i am not able to view when i ran script.

output:

```
Clearing state...

done
```

Comment: Which shell? There are more than one.

Comment: Do you mean you want to change the actual prompt depending on output from a command (like instead of e.g. a simple `$` you want `some output$`)? Then read the documentation for your shell, it's most likely in there.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Where did you get the idea of the OP wants to do anything with the _prompt_? It's not mentioned at all.

Comment: i am using in ubuntu it is stored in /bin/bash(Bourne Again SHell).  @ pileborg i have printf in application i am invoking from script, application is success but i am not able to see printf. I am new to scripting.

Comment: @MarcellFülöp Because of the text "print them on shell prompt" in the question.

Comment: Can you please show some example code, preferably both from the command and the script. The best would be if you could make a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) to show us.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I see... A little misleading indeed.

Answer (score 0):

The standard output of your script is inherited by the programs you run from the script.  You can redirect individual programs, or capture their output into a variable.

```
#!/bin/sh
one_output=$(one -foo "bar" -baz <quux)
echo "the output from 'one' was '$one_output'"
two -pounds "$1" >two_out
echo "the output from 'two' is in the file 'two_out'"
cat two_out
echo "here is the output from 'three'"
three
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [recent thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18580421/determining-when-cd-drawer-has-been-closed/18590806#18590806). An example of it shows how you would be able to compile C code on runtime.

Forwarding a summary here, basically the concept is like this. You could also add more flags or other enhancements like compilation checks to it.

```
#!/bin/sh

OUTPUT_BINARY=/tmp/some_binary_name

# Compile the code.

gcc -o "$OUTPUT_BINARY" -xc - <<EOF
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    printf("Hello world.\n");
    return 0;
}
EOF

# Run the code.

"$OUTPUT_BINARY"

# Delete it.

rm -f "$OUTPUT_BINARY"
```

There may even be some ways to not to use a filesystem file, just a space or pipe, but that's basically it.